# Tab freezes when using browser forward button for page accessed via Link

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a minimal Next.JS app with two pages: a home page and a dashboard page. I have an nav bar at the top of all pages with a Link object that links to the dashboard page. When I click the Link and arrive at the dashboard page, I press the browser back button. This works (I arrive at the home page). Then I press the browser forward button, intending to go to the dashboard page. Here the browser freezes.

I added a console.log statement inside the dashboard, and it appears infinitely in the console, implying the page is reloaded endlessly.

Why is this the case? I also noticed that if I manually type in `localhost:3000/dashboard` instead of clicking the `Link` object, the problem does not appear.

Any ideas of why this is? Here is the relevant code:

```
/* HOMEPAGE: app/page.js */
import React from 'react'; 
export default function LandingPage()
{
    return <div>LandingPage</div>;
};

/* DASHBOARD: app/dashboard/page.js */
"use client";
export default async function Dashboard()
{
    // This gets printed infinitely in the console
    console.log("Dashboard");

    return <div>Dashboard</div>;
}

/* APPBAR: app/components/AppBar.js */
"use client";
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function AppBar({})
{
    return (
        <nav className="mb-0 px-5 py-5 my-0 ttext-gray-800 text-center dark: bg-white flex justify-between items-left shadow-[#ccc] shadow-md z-50 relative">
            <Link href="#" className="text-xl font-bold text-gray-900">MySite</Link>
            <div>
                {/* This is the link I am clicking */}
                <Link href="/dashboard" className="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 px-5">Dashboard</Link>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

/* ROOT LAYOUT: app/layout.js */
import './globals.css'
import AppBar from './components/AppBar';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <AppBar />
                <main className="max-w mx-auto">
                {children}
                </main>
            </body>
        </html>
  );
}
```

I am using Next.js v13.4.1.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Removing the `async` from the Dashboard function, as @TheKritsakon correctly notes, does solve the issue. However, in my actual code, I make a call to an asynchronous function (I removed it to simplify the example here)

Answer (score 1):

As i've made a simple research it appears that babel has some issue to reference the component name that are exported as **async**
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3786.

There's some specific reason why you exported the component as async ?

```
"use client";
export default function Dashboard()
{
    // This gets printed infinitely in the console
    console.log("Dashboard");

    return <div>Dashboard</div>;
}
```

Comment: It's async because I call an asynchronous function to receive the dashboard data. However, I've removed all that so as to make it a minimal example.

Comment: Having said that, removing the `async` does fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I went through your code and your approach seems to be correct.
I also went through the docs [Pages and Layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts).
It seems like a bug in nextjs.

I can just suggest a simple temporary workaround for this.
In your app/components/AppBar.js file.

Replace

```
<Link href="/dashboard" className="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 px-5">Dashboard</Link>
```

with

```
<a href="/dashboard" className="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 px-5">Dashboard</a>
```

**Please note that navigating forward and backward with high speed
may cause this issue again. Hence filing an issue with nextjs is suggested.**

Or,alternatively,remove async from your dashboard page and create a separate async function and call it from your dashboard function. Something like

```
/* DASHBOARD: app/dashboard/page.js */
"use client";

async function DashboardHelper() {
    return "example";
}

export default function Dashboard() {
    console.log("called");
    DashboardHelper().then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(console.log);
    return <div>Dashboard</div>;
}
```

**Navigating forward and backward with high speed won't cause any issues in the above workaround.**

Hope it is helpful.
Thanks :)